# how to combine array of object fast or in optimized way

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, loops

I have two Array of objects `[{id:'KS001', name: 'albedo'}]` this is the first array which consist of 900+ objects.

```
{
  "changePoints": [
    {
      "Point": {
        "name": "001",
        "id": "KS001",
        "siteID": "258628",
        "connectorGroups": [
          {
            "connectorGroupID": 1,
            "connectors": [
              {
                "connectorID": "1",
                "connectorStatus": "AVAILABLE"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "connectorGroupID": 2,
            "connectors": [
              {
                "connectorID": "2",
                "connectorStatus": "AVAILABLE"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
  ],
}
```

this is the second array that contains objects  which have a point and id this id map with the first array as an identifier I need to check each `connectorStatus` in the second array with the corresponding id  and add a new key to the first array `status` set "AVAILABLE" else not "NOT AVAILABLE"

I need to find the fastest way to do this

Comment: Is the 'name' is also same in both objects?

Comment: no some time name will be same but not always

Answer (score 0):

```
const object1 = {
  name: 'Flavio'
}

const object2 = {
  age: 35
}
const object3 = {...object1, ...object2 } //{name: "Flavio", age: 35}


const a = { b: 1, c: 2 };
const d = { e: 1, f: 2 };

const ad = { ...a, ...d }; // { b: 1, c: 2, e: 1, f: 2 }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: There is more to the question than just the title.